# Warning in Resharper "Return value of pure method is not used"

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory, resharper

I have a quick question regarding a warning that I am getting from Resharper in Visual studio on a c# project that I am working. The warning is:

> " Return Value of pure method is not used"

The method where this is happening is as below:

```
 private static bool FilePathHasInvalidChars(string userInputPath)
    {
        try
        {
            //this is where the warning occurs:
            Path.GetFullPath(userInputPath);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(String.Format(
                "The Program failed to run due to invalid characters or empty " + 
                "string value for the Input Directory. " + 
                "Full Path : <{0}>. Error Message : {1}.",
                userInputPath, e.Message), e);
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

I think I know why the warning is happening.
I am using `Path.GetFullPath(path)` only for the purpose of catching all exceptions to do with invalid characters. The path is to be supplied as input by the user therefore I do not actually use the result of the `Path.GetFullPath(userInputPath)`. The only use I have for it is on a check that I have for this method is on a check that I do on the main method to ensure the path supplied is not empty or does not have any invalid characters.

The place where I use the above method is as below:

```
if (FilePathHasInvalidChars(inputDirectory))
{
     return;
}
```

Basically it is just an exit point before program commences execution using an invalid parameter.

I was wondering if this warning would cause any issues or if I am misusing the `Path.GetFullPath` method in a way which will cause me problems in the future?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nope, that should not cause any problems for you, as this is in fact how you do want to use it.

The Resharper hint in this case is just a pointer in case you've forgotten to create a variable in which to keep the data you've fetched. Since you're just validating, and don't actually need that data, you should be fine.

**Edit:** Note that you can avoid the hint, and make it clear that this is on purpose by using a specific Resharper comment, like this:

```
// ReSharper disable once ReturnValueOfPureMethodIsNotUsed
Path.GetFullPath(userInputPath);
```

---

***Edit #2:*** [SynerCoder is probably right though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20606138/336648), about `System.IO.Directory.Exists()` being a better option for your specific purpose...

Comment: Thanks Kjartan. Just wanted to make sure that it is ok. I will dissable the warning in this case. :D

Answer (score 7):

In your sample code you catch `Exception` which can be any of the following: `ArgumentException`, `SecurityException`, `ArgumentNullException`, `NotSupportedException`, `PathTooLongException`, but the one that is being thrown when path contains invalid characters is only `ArgumentException` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Furthermore,

> I am using Path.GetFullPath(path) only for the purpose of catching all exceptions to do with invalid characters.

you should rather use the following code, and omit the exception handling:

```
foreach (char invalidChar in Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
{
    if (userInputPath.Contains(invalidChar))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Hi YuriY. Thanks for the input. Originally my code was catch (ArgumentException). But after I saw that the Path.GetFullPath produced all the other exceptions that you mention I decided to catch them as well. This way I can catch it early if a user provides an empty string, or if a user wants to do something where they are not allowed. :)

Comment: Agreed with Yuriy. I just thought of a shorthand for Yuriy's function code:
`return userInputPath.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) >= 0 ? true : false`

Answer (score 6):

You should not use your own method for checking if the path is illegal. Since you are checking a directory (`inputDirectory`) you should use the following code:

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(inputDirectory))
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: I could do that. The reason why I am not doing it is because I use this method to validate another path which does not exist but which is created via Directory.CreateDirectory therefore this is a good way I found to check multiple issues with a path provided by a user.