# OrderBy does not work when sort a list and Resharper also displays a warning "return value of pure method not used"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, resharper

I have consulted [Warning in Resharper "Return value of pure method is not used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606022/warning-in-resharper-return-value-of-pure-method-is-not-used) post but have not found the solution

Take a look at my code

```
var listDetail = (from p in Expense.GetAll()
    where p.Group == "001"
    select new ExpenseViewModel()
    {
        ExpenseC = p.ExpenseC,
        Group = p.Group,
        Cost = p.Cost,
    }).ToList();
listDetail.OrderBy(p => p.ContainerSizeI); //warning displayed at OrderBy with content "return value of pure method not used"
```

As a result, the `listDetail` variable is not sorted in ascending order as I want

Comment: Move the OrderBy to the end of the query above it, before the ToList. You're creating an ordered enumerable but aren't assigning the result to anything.

Comment: Do you know what a "pure method" is?

Comment: hi Eric Lippert, That is the warning of the resharper

Comment: no, "pure method" is not a warning. Read this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function
OrderBy is pure method. Why do you call this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the OrderBy into your method chain.

```
var listDetail = (from p in Expense.GetAll()
where p.Group == "001"
select new ExpenseViewModel()
{
    ExpenseC = p.ExpenseC,
    Group = p.Group,
    Cost = p.Cost,
})
.OrderBy(p => p.ContainerSizeI)
.ToList();
```